# How can I create a Map<Id, Account> from a List<sObject> parameter when I know all the records are Accounts?

Tags: map, reflection, type

I'm doing some work with the [ESAPI Library](https://github.com/forcedotcom/force-dot-com-esapi). In particular, when updating records it is used to enforce FLS with the following method:

```
global SFDCAccessControlResults.UpdateResults updateAsUser(
    Map<ID, sObject> objMap,
    List<String> fieldsToUpdate
) {}
```

Example call:

```
try {
    List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = [select LastName,id from Contact];
    // Make some changes to contacts LastName field...
    SFDCAccessControlResults.UpdateResults res = 
        ESAPI.accessController().updateAsUser(
            new Map<ID, Contact>(contactsToUpdate), 
            new List<String>{'LastName'}
        );
    contactsToUpdate = res.getUpdatedObjects();
} catch (SFDCAccessControlException e) {
    // error handling
}
```

Note the need to explicitly convert the input list `contactsToUpdate` into a `Map<Id, Contact>`. I find this a bit unwieldy and would rather just pass in the existing list of contacts and let the underlying method sort out the Map conversion.

As a quick first attempt I added another method signature to [`SFDCAccessController`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/force-dot-com-esapi/blob/c6ae2951878d46f5d3d834f82374bcd533d2cbf7/src/classes/SFDCAccessController.cls) that did just that:

```
global SFDCAccessControlResults.UpdateResults updateAsUser(List<sObject> objs) {
    Map<ID, sObject> objMap = new Map<ID, sObject>(objs);

    // Note: This is only going to build up the field set for the first sObject in the collection.
    // If different sObjects have different fields then they will be ignored.
    Set<String> keySet = objs.get(0).getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().keySet();
    keySet.remove('Id');
    List<String> fieldsToUpdate = new List<string>(keySet); 

    Schema.SObjectType objType = objs.get(0).getSObjectType();

    return getACImpl().updateAsUser(objMap, fieldsToUpdate, objType);   
}
```

However, this fails with the message:

> System.TypeException: Operation only applies to concrete SObject value map types: SObject

This makes sense as a generic SObject could be any number of actual concrete sObject types.

That leaves the question - **How can I create a Map from the ID to the concrete type of the sObjects?**

Answer (score 6):

Here is one approach I've come up with using [Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) and `newInstance()`.

As anonymous apex:

```
Account acc = new Account(Name='Test');
insert acc;

List<sObject> accounts = new List<Account>();
accounts.add(acc);

Schema.SObjectType listObjType = accounts.getSObjectType();

//Instantiate a Map based on the input list sObject type.
Type mapType = Type.forName('Map<Id, '+listObjType+'>');

Map<Id, sObject> foo = (Map<Id, sObject>)mapType.newInstance();
foo.put(acc.Id, acc);
System.assertEquals(listObjType, foo.getSObjectType());
```

As a method to do the conversion:

```
private Map<Id, sObject> convertListToStronglyTypedMap(List<sObject> inputList) {
    Schema.SObjectType listObjType = inputList.getSObjectType();

    // Seems to work. Consider listObjType.getDescribe().getName()
    Type mapType = Type.forName('Map<Id, '+listObjType+'>');

    Map<Id, sObject> outputMap = (Map<Id, sObject>)mapType.newInstance();
    outputMap.putAll(inputList);

    return outputMap;
}
```